# Call TextSwitcher's SetText without using the fade animation

Tags: android, string, animation, settext

I'm trying to implement a TextSwitcher in my calculator app, it works and animates fine, but under some circumstances I want it NOT to animate the Text Changing process (change text like a simple textView)

Example:

Button A clicked --> Change the Value with a nice fade animation 
Button B clicked --> Change The Value without any particular animation

what should I do? Is there another method available for setting text without the animation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes: [`setCurrentText()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextSwitcher.html#setCurrentText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29).

> Sets the text of the text view that is currently showing. This does
>   not perform the animations.